# How do I optimize imports in Python using PyCharm?

Tags: python

Wanting to expand my horizons I decided to pick up programming and I've read that python is very beginner-friendly, knowing this I downloaded the program in addition to the PyCharm text editor and started to write some small stuff like print commands and the like. However, I wanted to start doing more and embarked on a mission to replicate a game off the internet, more specifically snake just to see how it all functions together in a cohesive manner. Every tutorial begins with "import" commands in addition to something like "math" and "random" directly after, turning red every single time. But for me, it just turns grey with the original orange "import" text also turning grey with a help icon saying to optimize my imports but just deleting my text altogether when I click it. I can find anything on the web to help me with what I'm dealing with leading me to believe that its probably an easy fix that I, for whatever reason can't seem to find. I really don't have a clue as to what to do and im increasingly becoming more and more frustrated.

Comment: Can you give us an example of your code?

Comment: Try to use `Ctrl Alt O` to optimize your imports, and then `Ctrl Alt L` to optimize source formatting

Answer (score 2):

That is okay, PyCharm is only signaling you that you haven't used that module yet. This can help Developers in large programs to save code and memory. Don't worry about it just ignore it and continue.